# Grep to subset in R

Tags: r

How can i grep all the gene names starting only with `"Gm"` from `data1[,7]`.

I tried `data2[grep("^Gm",data2$Genes),];` but it extract the entire row which starts with `"Gm"`.

```
data1[,7] <-

[1] "Ighmbp2,Mrpl21,Cpt1a,Mtl5,Gal,Ppp6r3,Gm23940,Lrp5"
[2] "Gm5852,Gm5773,Tdpoz4,Tdpoz3,Gm9116,Gm9117,Tdpoz5"
[3] "Arhgap15,Gm22867"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to split the string (`strsplit(..`) by `,` and then extract words in the output (which is a list, so `lapply` can be used) that begin with "Gm" using `grep`. (`^`- denotes the beginning of word/string)

```
 lapply(strsplit(Genes, ','), function(x) grep('^Gm', x, value=TRUE))
 #[[1]]
 #[1] "Gm23940"

 #[[2]]
 #[1] "Gm5852" "Gm5773" "Gm9116" "Gm9117"

 #[[3]]
 #[1] "Gm22867"
```

Or you could extract the words by `stri_extract_all` from `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_all_regex(Genes, 'Gm[[:alnum:]]+')
```

Or if you need it as a vector, you can use `unlist` on the above output or use `gsub` to remove those words that don't begin with "Gm" (`\\b(?!Gm)\\w+\\b`) and `,', then use`scan`.

```
 scan(text=gsub('\\b(?!Gm)\\w+\\b|,', ' ',
             Genes, perl=TRUE), what='', quiet=TRUE)
 #[1] "Gm23940" "Gm5852"  "Gm5773"  "Gm9116"  "Gm9117"  "Gm22867"
```

#### Update

If you need to remove all the words starting with `Gm`

```
 scan(text=gsub('\\bGm\\w+\\b|,', ' ', Genes, perl=TRUE),
                     what='', quiet=TRUE)
 # [1] "Ighmbp2"  "Mrpl21"   "Cpt1a"    "Mtl5"     "Gal"      "Ppp6r3"  
 # [7] "Lrp5"     "Tdpoz4"   "Tdpoz3"   "Tdpoz5"   "Arhgap15"
```

#### data

```
Genes <- c("Ighmbp2,Mrpl21,Cpt1a,Mtl5,Gal,Ppp6r3,Gm23940,Lrp5", 
    "Gm5852,Gm5773,Tdpoz4,Tdpoz3,Gm9116,Gm9117,Tdpoz5",
    "Arhgap15,Gm22867")
```

Comment: @akrun..it worked well. Now what if i want to remove all the gene names starting with "Gm" from my data frame?

Comment: @Cath Thank you.  You are great!